# how to get unvoted post count in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am using [Thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem for creating vote function. I have 3 tables - Post, User and Vote where Post is **acts_as_voteable** and User is **acts_as_voter**.

Model Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :user_type
  acts_as_voteable
  validates_presence_of :title,:content
  default_scope order: 'posts.created_at DESC'
end
```

Model Vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :for_voter, lambda { |*args| where(["voter_id = ? AND voter_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
    scope :for_voteable, lambda { |*args| where(["voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
    scope :recent, lambda { |*args| where(["created_at > ?", (args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]) }
    scope :descending, order("created_at DESC")
    belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :voter, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :vote, :voter, :voteable

end
```

Model User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
   has_secure_password
   acts_as_voter
   has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now I want to count posts number which are ***NOT VOTED***. I am trying to do like this..

```
<%= Post.joins(:votes).where("dont_know_how_to_write_condition").count %>
```

Any help?? Thanks in advance

Comment: is this mysql or postgresql?

Comment: in development mode i am using sqlite and in production mode i am using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work in sqlite, it should on postgresql though.

```
  def self.not_voted
    joins("left outer join votes on votes.voteable_id = posts.id").
    where("votes.id is null")
  end
```

Then:

```
Post.not_voted.count
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do that condition in SQL with NOT EXISTS but they are very heavy queries. If this si going to be an action facing the public or performed multiple times, it might be too heavy to do it like that. I would recommend you to denormalize the tables and include a count of votes on the post. Just use an observer on vote creation and deletion to update the vote count for the post. The query then would be like

```
Post.where('votecount = 0')
```

This query is much lighter and scalable than the previous one